# eval and setTimeout in a loop

Tags: javascript, eval, settimeout

I'm holding code lines in an array, and trying to run them cell by cell with setTimeout().

This executes the code well:

```
for (i=0; i<restorePoints.length; i++){
    eval(restorePoints[i]);
}
```

but I want to have a short delay between every iteration:  i want to use setTimeout() instead of eval().  for some reason none of those work:

```
for (i=0; i<restorePoints.length; i++){
    setTimeout(restorePoints[i],1000);
}
```

or

```
for (i=0; i<restorePoints.length; i++){
    setTimeout(eval(restorePoints[i]),1000);
}
```

how do I do it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is fast. It will create all timeouts in a row, so all timeouts will fire at the same time. You can either make the time depended on the loop variable, i.e. increasing the time in every iteration, or, what I would do, use only one timeout and a recursive call:

```
(function() {
    var data = restorePoints;
    var run = function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var entry = data[i];
            if(entry) {
                eval(entry);
                run(i+1);
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
    run(0);
}());
```

---

Note that there is a difference between `eval(string)` and `setTimeout(string, ...)` apart from the delay:

`eval` will evaluate the parameter in the current scope while `setTimeout` (and `setInterval`) will evaluate it in the global scope.

This might be relevant to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do it either of those ways, you'll need to wrap the function call in an anonymous function:

```
for (i=0; i<restorePoints.length; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){eval(restorePoints[i]}),1000);
}
```

Otherwise you're not setting the eval to fire in a timeout, you're setting the result of the executing Javascript code (whatever that might be in this case) to be the thing setTimeout is opperating against.

Comment: That will still fire all the timeouts at the same time. Passing a function to `setTimeout` is not necessary here as it will evaluate the string as well (only `setTimeout(eval(restorePoints[i]),1000);` is wrong).